# How to intercept click and do something before and after?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to intercept the click of a button to do something before and after.

How to trigger the original click?

```js
const el = document.querySelector(selector);
if (!el) { return; }

# Save original onclick
const onclick = el.onclick;

# Change onlick
el.onclick = async function (event) {
    console.log('Before click');

    # TODO: call the orignal onclick? <-------- ???
    onclick.call(event);

    console.log('After click');
}
```

I get the following output

```
BEFORE CLICK
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: onclick is null
```

Comment: What does it mean to... do something before a click happens? How do you predict a click?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. The code above already intercepts the click by changing the onclick function. Now I am trying to see how to run the original code from there.

Comment: It is giving you `null` because there was no previous `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

That is a little strange behavior. But I think you can use: `onhover` and `onblur` events.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Good idea. I will keep trying replacing the onlick function for now, though.

Comment: Also, you can check more events maybe some of them can help with your requirement: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp

Answer (score 1):

Since you can [only have one `onclick` handler at a time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) (when using `Element.onclick`), we just need to invoke the old function inside our new function. Here's the modified version of your code as you are likely intending:

```js
var selector = ".blue";
window.onload = function() {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (!el) {
    return;
  }
  // Add an initial onclick to test
  el.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("first onclick called");
  };

  // Save original onclick
  const onclick = el.onclick;

  // Change onlick
  el.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log('Before click');

    // Call the orignal onclick
    if (onclick !== null) {
      onclick(event);
    }

    console.log('After click');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="blue">Blue (click me)</div>
```

Also note, you can use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add multiple `eventListener`s instead without needing to handle the old `eventListener`